# C style regarding fprintf

Tags: c, file-io, coding-style

If a certain program has many lines of code that print a string to a file, which of the following is preferred? How important is it that I use the preferred format?

```
fprintf(file, "%s", "string to file");
fprintf(file, "string to file");
```

Comment: It comes down to what you're writing and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fprintf(file, "%s", "string to file");
fprintf(file, "string to file");
```

If the string to be printed is variable in any way the former version is the preferred one, if the strings are constants, hard coded, then it is also save to use the latter.

The danger with using the latter version with variable strings is that an evil mind could enter conversion specifiers (`%d`, `%s`, ...) into the string which then would make the code pull something from the stack which was not meant to be pulled. This leads to mayor security issues.

Comment: Yes, because if your variable contains something like a %s, you are screwed with the latter.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only printing a string, you should prefer to use `fputs()`:

```
fputs("string to file", file);
```

It uses less overhead than `fprintf()` since it does no formatting. It does not have the pit falls of the second version of `fprintf()` you show, since it doesn't treat `%` specially.

Comment: I'll look into fputs, and probably suggest that we switch to that.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer some version without any formatting, like

```
int fprint(FILE* file, char* s) {
  size_t ch_size = sizeof(char);
  size_t str_size = (strlen(s) + 1) * ch_size; 
  return fwrite(s , ch_size, str_size, file);
}

fprint(file, "string to file");
```